# GET response data from request promise giving error

Tags: node.js, bluebird, request-promise

Using  request promise module to do a post API call. The code is to get 'city' detail from the google maps api JSON output as below:

```
 var rp = require('request-promise');
    ............
    app.get('/check_promise', function(req,res) {
      var option1 = {
          url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Florence',
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          json: true
      }

      rp(option1)
        .then(function(response) {
          console.log(response.data.results[0].formatted_address);

        })

        .catch(function(error){
          console.log(error);
        });
    });
```

But the

```
console.log(response.data.results[0].formatted_address);
```

gives the below error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined
    at C:\Users\Laxmi\devapp\server.js:208:33
    at tryCatcher (C:\Users\Laxmi\devapp\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.j
s:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Users\Laxmi\devapp\node_modules\blu
ebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Users\Laxmi\devapp\node_modules\bluebird\js\re
lease\promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Users\Laxmi\devapp\node_modules\bluebird\js\r
elease\promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Users\Laxmi\devapp\node_modules\bluebird\js\r
elease\promise.js:693:18)
    at Async._drainQueue (C:\Users\Laxmi\devapp\node_modules\bluebird\js\release
\async.js:133:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (C:\Users\Laxmi\devapp\node_modules\bluebird\js\releas
e\async.js:143:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (C:\Users\Laxmi\devapp\node_modules\bluebird\
js\release\async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:789:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:751:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:722:5)
```

How to resolve the error to console log the city data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`console.log(response.results[0].formatted_address)`

Comment: Am getting the error:

SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: Can you print ‘response’

Comment: console.log(response) gives me the output as available here
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Florence

Comment: edited the answer, there is no `data` field the the response object.